# Jscript Display Template on SharePoint List

Tags: javascript, custom-list, sharepoint-views

I have a very simple JScript that replaces a list view value with an image based upon criteria.  Seems to work ok, but the return view is a small with box with a line through it.  My images are 20px x 20px.  Is there a permissions issue or image size issue I am missing?

[image]

```
(function () {

    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "ProspectRate": {
            "View": StatusFieldViewTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function StatusFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {



    if (ctx.CurrentItem.ProspectRate <=25)
    {
        return "<img src='/SiteAssets/Pick_Red-01.png'>";
    }
    if (ctx.CurrentItem.ProspectRate > 25 && ctx.CurrentItem.ProspectRate <=50)
    {
        return "<img src='/SiteAssets/Pick_Orange-01.png'>";
    }
    if (ctx.CurrentItem.ProspectRate > 50 && ctx.CurrentItem.ProspectRate < 70)
    {
        return "<img src='/SiteAssets/Pick_Yellow-01.png'>";
    }
    if (ctx.CurrentItem.ProspectRate >70)
    {
        return "<img src='/SiteAssets/Pick_Green-01.png'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using the fully qualified url for the img src. So use "https://myserver.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Pick_Green-01.png"

Answer (score 2):

This was a very simple fix that involved putting the entire URL into the return statement.