# Change View in SharePoint list to include field value with an image with Java Script Display Template

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-views

I have the following script that replaces the field value with an image.  Works great, but I would like the field value and the image to be displayed.  I have tried using  img + field.value  to no avail.  How do I get both?

```
(function () {

    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "ProspectRate": {
            "View": StatusFieldViewTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function StatusFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {



    if (ctx.CurrentItem.ProspectRate <=25)
    {
        return "<img src='https://mysite.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Pick_Red-01.png'>";
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your previous [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240507/jscript-display-template-on-sharepoint-list), you are able to set image. Now instead of using  tag use div tag and set image as a background of the div and div will have content as the field value.

Try something like this

```
    (function () {

    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "ProspectRate": {
            "View": StatusFieldViewTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function StatusFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {



    if (ctx.CurrentItem.ProspectRate <=25)
    {
        return "<div background-image: url('<url of the pic>'');'>"+ctx.CurrentItem.ProspectRate +"</div>";
}}
```